# Altium: unable to slice a polygon pour on a mechanical layer

Tags: pcb, altium

In Altium 18.1, I need to create a layer for a flex stiffener.  I created a mechanical layer
and did a polygon pour for the entire board area.
Now I want to slice the polygon pour to remove the pour from flex bend lines.

It appears that slicing a pour on a mechanical layer doesn't work. The slice line vanishes
on the last click.

I am able slice a pour on a signal layer.  Am I stuck using a signal layer for a stiffener
or is there another solution?

Comment: Solid regions seem promising.  Is there a way to copy and paste cutouts?

Answer (score 2):

Polygon pours are meant for copper layers so don't behave on mechanical layers.
I would suggest working backwards... draw your 'cut' on the mechanical layer using a line and then add a note to the manufacturer.  (Mechanical layers aren't copper so won't be treated by the PCB house as anything but notes).
An alternative is to draw the two (or more) stiffener regions using Place->Solid Region but draw then around the cut marks you've already placed.

Comment: I second the vote for using solid regions instead of polygons. They function much better on mechanical layers.